# How to reorder a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, transform

Let's suppose I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1200
            [1] => 2541
            [2] => 2540
            [3] => 2539
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Television
            [1] => Monitor
            [2] => Car
            [3] => Bike
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Electrodomestic
            [1] => Computer Stuff
            [2] => Vehicle
            [3] => Vehicle
        )
)
```

And I would like to arrange it individually, like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1200
            [1] => Television
            [2] => Electrodomestic
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2541
            [1] => Monitor
            [2] => Computer Stuff
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2540
            [1] => Car
            [2] => Vehicle
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2539
            [1] => Bike
            [2] => Vehicle
        )
)
```

How can I do that?

I would like to reoder my simple array (from data I extracted from a REGEX) into an array containing my individual "objects".

Comment: Create a `foreach` loop, add values with same indexes to new item.

Comment: @u_mulder do you have an example? What's the name of this procedure so I can google it and learn more?

Comment: There's no procedure. Start with `foreach` loop.

Comment: The name of the procedure is "php loop build array". Try it and if you have problems, post a sample of what you came up with so far. Figure out how to build an array in the structure you need to begin with. Then see if it's still difficult to loop and build anew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have nothing to do, so here's a possible solution:

```
$a = Array
(
    '0' => Array
        (
            '0' => 1200,
            '1' => 2541,
            '2' => 2540,
            '3' => 2539,
        ),
    '1' => Array
        (
            '0' => 'Television',
            '1' => 'Monitor',
            '2' => 'Car',
            '3' => 'Bike',
        ),
    '2' => Array
        (
            '0' => 'Electrodomestic',
            '1' => 'Computer Stuff',
            '2' => 'Vehicle',
            '3' => 'Vehicle',
        )
);

// take a size of every subarray
$t = sizeof($a[0]);
// do a loop
$new_a = [];
for($i =0; $i < $t; $i ++) {
    // `array_column` extracts every value 
    // with key `$i` from each element of 
    // `$a` array and adds these values
    // to a new array
    $new_a[] = array_column($a, $i);
}

echo'<pre>',print_r($new_a),'</pre>';
```

**Warning**: `array_column` introduced in `php5.5`.

Comment: If you're still feeling idle, do explain a bit how this works, so OP gets some educational value out of it, and +1.

Comment: No need to explain, the code is all there. I see you got the count of keys then looped through it with array_column. Very interesting.